# Realloc messing with my array of structs

Tags: c, pointers, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I am doing a school project where I can manage a Zoo information. A Zoo has Areas, where they are saved in an array of structures. That Areas have a maximum of 3 neighbour Areas. When the program is initialized, it must read a file with some information of the Areas already. And it works pretty well. I got in the structure the **char areas[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMFz1.png)[10]** so I can save the neighbour areas names, and then search in the array of structures with the Areas and save the neighbour areas in an array of pointers to the struct (**Area *adj[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMFz1.png)**). It works fine until the **total** hits 6 Areas. I found the source of the problem. The realloc is messing with the values. But I don't really now why and how to fix it. Can someone help me? Thanks.

## struct.h

```
typedef struct area Area;
struct area{
    char id[10];
    int peso, nadj;

    char areas[3][10];
    Area *adj[3]; ///ponteiros para areas adjacentes
};
```

## main.c

```
int menu()
{
    int op;

    printf("\n\n1 - Mostrar Areas");
    printf("\n2 - Nova Area");
    printf("\n3 - Eliminar Area");
    printf("\n4 - Terminar");
    do{
        printf("\nOpcao: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf(" %d", &op);
        putchar('\n');
    }while(op<1 || op>4);
    return op;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int i, total;
    FILE *f;    ///FICHEIRO COM ÁREAS
    Area *areas = NULL; ///IMPORTANTE ESTAR A NULL PARA FUNCIONAR

    areas = le_fich("zoo.txt", &total);

    do{
        i = menu();
        switch(i){
            case 1: mostrar_areas(areas, total); break;
            case 2: areas = nova_area(areas, &total); break;
            case 3: printf("Funcao por introduzir."); break;
            case 4: printf("Funcao por introduzir."); break;
        }        
    }while(i != 4);

    free(areas);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

## funcoes.c

```
Area *nova_area(Area *p, int *total){
    int i, igual;
    Area *novo;
    char nome_area[TAM], nome_areadj[TAM];


    printf("********BEFORE p[1].adj[0]: %s\n", p[1].adj[0]->id);

    novo = realloc(p, ((*total)+1) * sizeof(Area));
    if(novo == NULL){
        printf("Erro na alocacao de memoria.\n");
        return p;
    }

    printf("******** AFTERp[1].adj[0]: %s\n", p[1].adj[0]->id);

    p = novo;   //CASO p TENHA MUDADO DE SITIO DEVIDO AO REALLOC
    *total = *total +1;

    do{
        printf("ID: ");
        scanf(" %10[^\n]", nome_area);

        igual = procura_area(p, nome_area, *total);
    }while(igual);

    strcpy(p[*total-1].id, nome_area);
    printf("Peso: ");
    scanf(" %d", &(p[*total-1].peso));
    do{
        printf("Nadj: ");
        scanf(" %d", &(p[*total-1].nadj));

        if(p[*total-1].nadj >= 4)
            printf("\tNumero de areas adjacentes excedidas.\n");
    }while(p[*total-1].nadj >= 4);

    for(i = 0; i < p[*total-1].nadj; i++){
        do{
                printf("Nome da area adjacente: ");
                scanf(" %10[^\n]", nome_areadj);
        }while(strcmp(nome_area, nome_areadj) == 0);

        p[*total-1].adj[i] = procura_areaAdj(p, nome_areadj, *total);
        //SE A AREA INSERIDA NAO FOR RECONHECIDA (NULL), O NUMERO DE ADJACENCIAS
        //É DIMINUÍDO
        if(p[*total-1].adj[i] == NULL){
//                p[*total-1].nadj -= p[*total-1].nadj; //AQUIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII DA ULTIMA VEZ

            p[*total-1].nadj--;
        }
        else if(p[*total-1].adj[i]->nadj < 3 && p[*total-1].adj[i] != NULL){
            atualiza_areas(p, nome_areadj, *total);
        }
        else{
            p[*total-1].nadj = 0;
            p[*total-1].adj[i] = NULL;
            printf("Numero maximo de areas adjacentes alcancado.\n");
        }
    }
//    printf("********DEPOISp[1].adj[0]: %s\n", p[1].adj[0]->id);
    return p;
}
```

Comment: @xing no, I just allocate memory for each Area. novo = realloc(p, ((*total)+1) * sizeof(Area));

Comment: Don't post images of text!

Comment: I didn't allocate memory to the array of pointers to the structure. Should I?

Comment: @Olaf Why not? It was ment to help, not confound

Comment: Which help do the images provide the text copy/pasted as code does not?

Comment: on the line `printf("******** AFTERp[1].adj[0]: %s\n", p[1].adj[0]->id);`  , using `p` causes undefined behaviour.  You should do `p = novo;` before doing that line.

Comment: @M.M It didn't work :/

Comment: @Olaf Already removed the pictures.

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is *Undefined Behavior* on most OS's as `fflush` applies to **output** streams. Simply use `for (int c = getchar(); c != '\n' && c != EOF; c = getchar()) {}` instead.

Comment: @DavidCoelho there are lots of problems in your code, you will have to fix them all. I would recommend learning how to use a debugger

Comment: @M.M I always clean and build. Teachers never said to use the debug option. Not even the clean and build tool actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already solve it. When I realloc the pointer to the Array of structures, I lose the location of the pointers inside of it. My solution was: when searching for the neighbour area, instead of returning a pointer of it, I send its index and manage the areas easily. So now there's no away of losing any pointer location.

## struct.h

```
///STRUCT PARA AS AREAS. INCLUI LISTA LIGADA typedef struct area Area; struct area{
    char id[10];
    int peso, nadj;
    
    char areas[3][10];
    int adj[3]; ///array de indices das areas adjacentes };
```

## funcoes.c

```
//when searching
int procura_areaAdj(Area *p, char *nome_areadj, int total){
    for(int i = 0; i < total; i++){        
        if(strcmp(nome_areadj, p[i].id) == 0){    //SE ENCONTROU RETORNA O INDICE 
            return i;
        }
    }
    
    return -1;   //SE NÃO ENCONTROU, RETORNA -1. PARA FUTURAS VALIDAÇÕES
}


//UPDATING ARRAY OF STRUCTURES VALUES
void atualiza_areas(Area *p, char *nome_areadj, int total){
    int i, j;

    if(total == 1)  //NAO EXISTEM ATUALIZACOES NA PRIMEIRA AREA INSERIDA
        ;
    else{
        for(i = 0; i < total; i++){        
            if(strcmp(nome_areadj, p[i].id) == 0){
                
                j=0;
                while(j < p[i].nadj)
                    j++;

                p[i].nadj++;
                p[i].adj[j] = total-1; //RETURNS LAST AREA INDEX 
                
            }
        }
    } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it

```
Area * nova_area (Area *p, int *total)
```

to:

```
Area * nova_area (Area **p, int *total)
```

You are passing Area by value.You need to pass the pointer of Area, so you can modify and reallocate it.
You will also need to change the realloc:

```
novo = realloc (*p, ((* total) +1) * sizeof (Area));
```